# Getting Google Place Photo from request

Tags: google-places-api

Hello everybody I a little confused with Google's Place Photo Request. I have my photo_reference and i put that into request form but what do i do with the request? Im stuck and have no idea how to proceed. I can copy paste the request url on my browser and get the photo so i know it a good vaild request. but how do i actually get the picture? Here is my sample request without my key of course.

```
 https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference="CoQBdwAAAFZwz6JNaNHCkR6T9omc9vHxvrV6DpClDLezqzxUOKcscEQAzB92MUZIbtDaJlOB7qX7kL-TIPXBK57mZB-gRX5RzvvZUaMw8u9aVetEtVeA-boJPQDZIhxf0gcrGj7zZ9CzYWQqz7fS8-Y-4I4hE7WBfQ6xqFqzngE1SoHw6vSMEhD6_abf6oML1e-Gt9Z67xsvGhQ-kEGM4j8g0atONhfgICacXWmSBg"&key=YOUR_KEY
```

Edit:
Could i use picasso?

```
 Uri GoogleUri = Uri.parse(GoogleUriString);

 Picasso.with(c).load(GoogleUri).into(googlepic);
```

GoogleUriString being the string i post above?

Edit2: Solved:
    To answer my own question because it takes a million years for people to answer on this site, yes it does work with picasso. For anyone else that is wondering/having the same problem.

Comment: What do you mean by *"how do i actually get the picture"*? You need to provide some context for your question.

Comment: What do I do with the request link, in order to get the image?

Comment: The answer depends on which programming language/framework you're using. We need more info to answer the question.

Comment: O wow im sorry, IM using android studio and using google api. Could i possibly use picasso to get the image? using this code:  GoogleUriString being the url i posted originally?                                        Uri GoogleUri = Uri.parse(GoogleUriString);


                Picasso.with(c).load(GoogleUri).into(googlepic);